# Find the time closest to current time with 5 date objects javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have the current time as currentTime.

And I have 5 date objects:

a = 2:20 am
b = 2:40 am
c = 3:00 am
d = 4:00 pm
e = 6:00 pm

The time is 3:30 pm

Now, keeping in mind that a to e have successfully been turned into Date() objects.

How would I cycle through those 5, given the current time, to determine which time comes closest to the current time, but after it. So for instance I want to find in this case that d is the next time coming.

I'm just not sure of the way to do that.

Comment: Use a `for` loop to iterate through them. Subtract the date from the target date and get the absolute value. Keep track of the closest - if the current iteration's date is closer, store that, otherwise move on.

Comment: A `Date` object only represents a full date-and-time.  Not just a time.  Are you saying that the times exist on every day?  So if the time was 7:00 pm, should I get 2:20 am on the next day?  Or return null?

Comment: @Ian - almost right, but not the absolute value. OP wants the nearest time *greater than* the current time. So discard negative values that result from the subtraction and only look at the positive ones.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Oops, I didn't see `, but after it.` :) You're right then!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// Given an array of Date objects and a start date,
// return the entry from the array nearest to the
// start date but greater than it.
// Return undefined if no such date is found.
function nextDate( startDate, dates ) {
    var startTime = +startDate;
    var nearestDate, nearestDiff = Infinity;
    for( var i = 0, n = dates.length;  i < n;  ++i ) {
        var diff = +dates[i] - startTime;
        if( diff > 0  &&  diff < nearestDiff ) {
            nearestDiff = diff;
            nearestDate = dates[i];
        }
    }
    return nearestDate;
}

var testDates = [
    new Date( 2013, 6, 15, 16, 30 ),
    new Date( 2013, 6, 15, 16, 45 ),
    new Date( 2013, 6, 15, 16, 15 )
];

console.log( nextDate( new Date( 2013, 6, 15, 16, 20 ), testDates ) );
console.log( nextDate( new Date( 2013, 6, 15, 16, 35 ), testDates ) );
```

console.log( nextDate( new Date( 2013, 6, 15, 16, 50 ), testDates ) );

Answer (score 0):

There might be a neater/faster way to do it, but I would make a second array with the differences between the value and the currentTime for a to e and then use this second array to `sort` the first array (take the diff of the diff of both values).